# Bluetooth device Integration in iphone

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbperipheralmanager

I want to fetch UUID of a bluetooth device (like iBeacon but not iBeacon) by scanning, but wasn't successful so far.

I have tried **CBPeripheral** but it's returned uuid does not match with the real values.

Please suggest me how to find UUID / MAC address of bluetooth devices.

I have used following Code:

```
 func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    if(!peripherals.contains(peripheral)) {
        print(peripheral.identifier)
        peripherals.append(peripheral)
    }
}
```

Comment: Which UUID are you reading? Not that you shouldn't be able to read the MAC Address not the real UUID which are a mix between timestamp, MAC address etc and might be different another time except if your pair with it.

Comment: CoreBluetooth does not provide access to the underlying MAC address of the peripheral. You could put a unique identifier in a characteristic on your peripheral which you could then read.